# Testcafe not saving cookies, resulting in malformed JWT

Tags: testing, cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been using testcafe for automated UI tests for an internal CRM. These tests worked well for the last 6 months, and then mysteriously started failing a week ago. The tests are able to log into our stage environment, but then once they attempt to hit our backend, the following error occurs:

```
UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed
   at /opt/app/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:100:22
   at /opt/app/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:155:18
   at /opt/app/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
   at process.fallback (/opt/app/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:563:15)
```

It looks like the cookies are not being saved:

[image: Network Cookies Tab]

I am currently using Testcafe 0.19.0, but have also attempted to upgrade to v0.22.0, but that did not solve the problem.

To my knowledge, there were no infrastructure changes that would cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following code as a work around and it seems to be working fine.

```
await t.wait(1500);
await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));
```

Comment: While your workaround may work under certain circumstances, it would be great if you provide a simple sample test case, so the TestCafe team can examine the real cause of the issue. As far as I can see, your CRM appears to be accessible via https://stg.uscompass.co/, but it requires login credentials.